# How to add a column for next date in an R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame of stocks and dates.  I want to add a "next date" column.  How should I do this?

The data is this:

```
df = data.frame(ticker = c("BHP", "BHP", "BHP", "BHP", "ANZ", "ANZ", "ANZ"), date = c("1999-05-31", "2000-06-30", "2001-06-29", "2002-06-28", "1999-09-30", "2000-09-29", "2001-09-28"))
df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date)
```

In human-readable form:

```
ticker   |   date
-----------------
BHP      | 1999-05-31
BHP      | 2000-06-30
BHP      | 2001-06-29
BHP      | 2002-06-28
ANZ      | 1999-09-30
ANZ      | 2000-09-29
ANZ      | 2001-09-28
```

What I want is to add a column for the next date:

```
ticker   |   date      |  next_date
------------------------------------
BHP      | 1999-05-31  |  2000-06-30
BHP      | 2000-06-30  |  2001-06-29
BHP      | 2001-06-29  |  2002-06-28
BHP      | 2002-06-28  |  NA          # (or some default value)
ANZ      | 1999-09-30  |  2000-09-29
ANZ      | 2000-09-29  |  2001-09-28
ANZ      | 2001-09-28  |  NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
group_by(ticker) %>% 
mutate(next_date = lead(date))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` from `base R` to do this

```
df$next_date <- with(df, ave(as.Date(date), ticker, FUN = function(x) c(x[-1], NA)))
df$next_date
#[1] "2000-06-30" "2001-06-29" "2002-06-28" NA           "2000-09-29" "2001-09-28" NA
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, next_date := shift(date, type = "lead"), by = ticker]
```

Comment: The first of your two solutions doesn't quite work.  Your data.table solution works fine.

Comment: @lebelinoz  For me, it is working fine using the example you showed.  actually, I meant `c(x[-1], NA)` but forgot to update it

Comment: @lebelinoz  Yes, I edited it.  I meant to say, originally, I copy/pasted it and then changed it on my system, but forgot to update the code.